# Can't access my array

Tags: java, arrays

My programme is to create a Train Route Finder using Java, first off as a command line programme then convert into a GUI. That's the least of my worries for now. I am currently stuck on one functionality of my system and that is to display the list of stops between two stations that the user previously input.

Now, I have been able to prompt the user to choose their stops (lines 3,149 - 3,171 in my code):

```
if(deptChoice == 1 && arrChoice == 2){

    List<String> stopList1_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner stopPick = new Scanner(System.in);
    stopPick.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    do {
        System.out.println("\nCurrent list of stops between Leicester to Loughborough is:\n\n" + stopList1_2);
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to add a new stop? (Please enter 'Yes' or 'No')\n");

        if (stopPick.next().startsWith("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("\nPlease type in the stop you wish to add to the route:\n");
            stopList1_2.add(stopPick.next());
        }

        else {
            break;
        }

    } while (true);

    String[] stopArr1_2 = stopList1_2.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent stops between Leicester to Loughborough is:\n\n" + Arrays.toString(stopArr1_2));

}
```

and the stops they type in are added to an array. When they are satisfied with the amount stops between the stations there are then the loop ends and it displays the array of stops between Station X and Station Y.

However, here comes the problem:

I want to then gain access to this previously created array with all the exact stops further up my code. In this "if" statement, if it is satisfied, then I want the array (stopArr1_2) to be displayed (in lines 3,019 - 3,021):

```
if(deptChoice == 1 && arrChoice == 2){
    System.out.println(""); //this should be where I call the array back to display itself
}
```

as those stops would correspond with the users choice of deptChoice == 1 (Station 1 = Leicester) to arrChoice == 2 (Station 2 = Loughborough).

I hope this is clear:

I basically want the array of stops inputted by the user to reappear when they choose Train Routes.

Here his my full code I made in Notepad++ I thought it would be better for you lot to see all of my code rather than small segments and it is commented.

Furthermore, to comprehend my problem run my programme. To understand my problem do this:

1) Compile Train.java (javac Train.java)

2) Run programme (java Train)

3) Pick Admin Menu (Number 5)

4) Pick Input Menu (Number 1)

5) Pick any two stations

6) Enter a couple of stops until you're happy

7) When it shows the final stops array for those two stations the programme seems to end so hopefully that is not an issue

8) Run programme again (java Train)

9) Pick Train Routes (Number 3)

10) Pick the SAME stations in the same order as you did before so it would find the array you just made

11) Now nothing will come up because, well, that's my problem. I don't know how to regain that array I just made for it.

Download link to my Train.java file (and Train.txt file if needed):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dy0pp9vyykwhrk/TrainJava.rar

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question in a formatted code-block. (although in this case, not all 3000-odd lines. Maybe start by breaking this up? That is much too long.)

Comment: I admire your effort in this question, but you need to improve it to get good answers. You need a [short, self contained, correct example](http://www.sscce.org/) and a concise but effective description of the problem. You want to minimize the barrier to answer.

Comment: `lines 3,149 - 3,171 in my code` Holy cow. How long is your code?

Comment: Dont mean to demoralise you - this is asking far too much. Please present one small enough problem you are facing ( along with your small code ) and you will get answers.

Comment: @gla3dr All done mate

Comment: @ZongZhengLi All done mate

Comment: I think before you do ANYTHING, is to modularize your code. Your code should read like English. Write your main as if you had any method available that works. Then after you're done that, start writing those methods the same way. Then write all the method that they use. And then you'll eventually have some methods at the end with very contained logic, and most of your code is very readable. Then finding these problems becomes much easier.

Comment: @Cruncher Lol, god help me but most of it is repeated code haha

Comment: "8) Run programme again" -- are you expecting that the data structure will still be around on a subsequent run of the program? Without saving it in a file or a database?

Comment: @DavidConrad Basically but I know it's not possible to do so without saving it to a file...how do I do that?

Comment: You need to decide what you want the file format to look like. Also, I'm a little unclear about the difference between picking stations and picking stops. And, if the user enters the same stations again, why do you need to get the old array back? Can't you just recreate it, since the user has entered the same data?

Answer (score 1):

Whats the location of your second block of code ? ( The code where you said you need access to the `List<String> stopList1_2` ) ?

1 If its in the *same class* but in a *different method* , then

Move this declaration 
`List<String> stopList1_2 = new ArrayList<String>();` ( currently in your first block of code ) to a class field.

BUT

2 If its in the *same class and also in the same method* as your first block of code, then

Move this declaration 
`List<String> stopList1_2 = new ArrayList<String>();` ( currently within the `if` statement of code ) to outside the `if` condition .

but treat this as a quick recipe for you problem at hand. More importantly - please read the [variable scoping rule and access specifiers in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html).

Comment: Okay but how do I return the array in a different part of my code?